# Balls and Urns with Two Color Balls

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In how many ways can we place 7 identical red balls and 7 identical blue balls into 5 distinct urns if each urn has at least 1 ball?

This is how I approached the problem:

1) Compute the number of total combinations if there were no constraints:

Placing just the red balls, allowing for empty urns:  $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1} = \binom{7+5-1}{5-1} = \binom{11}{4} = 330$.  There are the same number of blue ball configurations.

Since each red ball configuration can have 330 possible blue ball configurations, then in total we should have $330^2 = 108900$

2) Compute the number of illegal configurations with 1, 2, 3 or 4 empty urns:

$r_1$ = ways to put 7 red balls into 1 urn  = $\binom{7-1}{1-1} = \binom{6}{0} = 1$
$r_2$ = ways to put 7 red balls into 2 urns = $\binom{7-1}{2-1} = \binom{6}{1} = 6$
$r_3$ = ways to put 7 red balls into 3 urns = $\binom{7-1}{3-1} = \binom{6}{2} = 15$
$r_4$ = ways to put 7 red balls into 4 urns = $\binom{7-1}{4-1} = \binom{6}{3} = $20

$b_1$ = ways to put 7 blue balls into 1 urn  = $r_1$
$b_2$ = ways to put 7 blue balls into 2 urns = $r_2$
$b_3$ = ways to put 7 blue balls into 3 urns = $r_3$
$b_4$ = ways to put 7 blue balls into 4 urns = $r_4$

$u_1$ = ways to pick 1 urn = $\binom{5}{1} = 5$
$u_2$ = ways to pick 2 urns = $\binom{5}{2} = 10$
$u_3$ = ways to pick 3 urns = $\binom{5}{3} = 10$
$u_4$ = ways to pick 4 urns = $\binom{5}{4} = 5$

# ways to put 7 red and 7 blue balls into 1, 2, 3, or 4 urns =
# ways to put 7 red and 7 blue balls into 5 urns where 1 or more urns are empty =

$r_1 b_1\binom{5}{1} + r_2 b_2\binom{5}{2} + r_3 b_3\binom{5}{3}  + r_4 b_4\binom{5}{4} = $

$1^2 \cdot 5 + 6^2 \cdot 10 + 15^2 \cdot 10 + 20^2 \cdot 5 = 4615$ = # of illegal configurations

3) Subtract the number of illegal configurations from the number of total configurations:

108900 - 4615 = 104285

Is this correct?  If not, could someone explain where either my logic breaks down or where I calculated something incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error lies in multiplying the number of ways to distribute $7$ red balls over $k$ non-empty urns by the number of ways to distribute $7$ blue balls over $k$ non-empty urns and treating that as the number of ways to distribute all $14$ balls over $2$ non-empty urns. You’re missing the distributions where $k$ urns are non-empty but not all of them contain both red and blue balls.

For a correct count, you can perform [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) like this: There are $5$ conditions for the $5$ urns to be non-empty. There are $\binom5k$ ways to choose $k$ particular conditions, and $\binom{7+(5-k)-1}{(5-k)-1}^2=\binom{11-k}7^2$ ways to violate them by distributing all balls to the remaining $5-k$ urns. Thus the number of admissible distributions is

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=0}^4(-1)^k\binom5k\binom{11-k}7^2
&=&
1\cdot\binom{11}7^2-5\cdot\binom{10}7^2+10\cdot\binom97^2-10\cdot\binom87^2+5\cdot\binom77^2
\\
&=&
49225\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

```
A=[ nchoosek(1:11,4)-ones(size(nchoosek(1:11,4))), diff(nchoosek(1:11,4),[],2) - ones(size(diff(nchoosek(1:11,4),[],2))), -nchoosek(1:11,4)+11*ones(size(nchoosek(1:11,4)))];
B=A(:, [1,5,6,7,11]);
valid=0;
for i=1:size(B,1)
    for j=1:size(B,1)
        C=B(i,:)+B(j,:);
        if (min(C) > 0) 
            valid=valid+1;
        end
    end
end
valid
```

the Matlab code above generates the right answer, which is 49225

one nice way to solve this sort of problems is through generating functions

[How to solve this distribution problem with generating functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161312/how-to-solve-this-distribution-problem-with-generating-functions)

I think you would be very interested to read Section 4.2 of Wilf's [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).

Note that what Wilf calls the sieve method is precisely inclusion-exclusion.

[Inclusion Exclusion vs. Generating Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108973/inclusion-exclusion-vs-generating-functions)